# SEC_ERROR_ADDING_CERT: Error adding certificate to database

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certutil

While trying to configure a valid SSL certificate for localhost on Ubuntu, I got the following error:

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "CT,c,c" -n "localhost" -i localhost.crt
```

> certutil: could not add certificate to token or database:
> SEC_ERROR_ADDING_CERT: Error adding certificate to database.

This certificate will be used in Nginx configuration, my goal is to avoid any errors in Google Chrome (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) as the certificate authority is untrusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurred because the certificate **was already registered using certutil previously**.

**Solution**

1. Delete the existing record

   `certutil -n localhost -D localhost.crt`
2. Then, create a new record

   `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "CT,c,c" -n "localhost" -i localhost.crt`

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth if anyone is suddenly getting this when trying to import a Let's Encrypt certificate you now need to point to the "**fullchain.pem**" file instead of the "**chain.pem**" file.